# Apache James Installation Issue - java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:

Tags: java, java-8, james, jdk1.7

I am trying to install apache james 3.3.0 in windows 7 service pack 1, in which both jd 1.7, and 1.8 already installed. But while running the james i am getting the below error.

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/ja
    mes/app/spring/JamesAppSpringMain : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

[jdk installation directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUmpP.png)

Answer (score 0):

This error comes from lower version of jvm. It means you are trying to run java 8 compiled jar with java 7 jvm.

Therefore java 7 says that class version is not recognized. You need to configure JAVA_HOME points 8 then re-run.

You can find what class version is supported by which jvm https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file#General_layout

Comment: do you know how to set classpath in apache james?

Comment: never used apache james before. but I used apache tomcat and it should be in some bat file under bin folder.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: I added

```
wrapper.java.command=/toolbox/jdk1.8.0_192/bin/java
```

near the top of conf/wrapper.conf .